# How do i send a song name which user typed in searchbar to an api

Tags: javascript, api

i'm going to get what song user types in searchbar and send it to an api using jquery ajax. but as you can see in the url it requires artist name "q = [artist name]".

Let's say the user types "eminem loose yourself" in searchbar how am i suppose to know which one of these words is the artist name so i store that value in a variable and put it in the url , send it THEN retrieve his array of songs.

```
    var settings = {
        method: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=eminem",
        headers: {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       // display the song on screen
    })
```

i could make another searchbar for artist name alone but that is not efficient.

Comment: The API should be managing the search query to return what it finds that matches. If not, then it's going to be quite the challenge to be able to determine which is artist name and which is song name, especially if typed incorrectly. You can also use the `data` option for AJAX to send the `q` variable and it's value. It depends on the API and how it accepts parameters.

Comment: you can only determine what the artist is if you have some dictionary of all artists and some way to interpret misspellings. do you have both of these features available?  What if the search query includes multiple artists? This seems like a pretty impossible task with just one text input

Comment: i understand. seems like i have to switch api or just make another input bar

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say which word is the Artist's name. What if the user will not type the Artist's name at all? If he searches for song name only.

You have to mention that specifically that input is meant to accept Artist's name only; use the `placeholder` attribute. You can also make use of the `select` element of the `form` tag. This way, the user has to select the artist name only from the predefined list.